# Geofence alert and remote feature

Tags: mdm, wso2-iot

I have 2 concerns.

**1. How can I configure geofence alert in WsO2iot3.1.0-Updte7?**
I did it in Update1 but according to documentation online: [Monitoring Devices Using Location Based Services](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Monitoring+Devices+Using+Location+Based+Services/)
`<GeoLocationConfiguration>` bloc is missing in cdm-config.xml file of Update7.

*This is missing geofence settings in cdm-config.xml file*

[image: This is missing geofence settings in cdm-config.xml file]

When I run the script `mvn clean install -f siddhi-geo-extention-deployer.xml`, and deploy Geo Analytics artifacts in devicemgt, nothing is displayed about geofence alerte (exit, enter, stationnary, speed) as in Update1.

*nothing is displayed about geofence alerte (exit, enter, stationnary, speed)*

[image: nothing is displayed about geofence alerte (exit, enter, stationnary, speed)]

**2. New remote feature in devicemgt**. We really appreciate but when we clic on active/connected device, it just in waiting device to connect status. Nothing is prompted.

Wainting on device to connect even when the device is active.

[image: Wainting on device to connect even when the device is active]

*Remote session is enabled in cdm-config.xml file.*

[image: Remote session is enabled in cdm-config.xml file]

Comment: To activate Geofence in Update8, I did mvn clean install -f on all .xml files in  IOTHOME/samples/ but normalement just installing device-plugins-deployer.xml should solve the problem.

Comment: But There are issues with  global speed limit alert and  history date settings in device location. They not save the data we seize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. How can I configure geofence alert in WsO2iot3.1.0-Updte7?**
From IoTS-3.1.0-Update 5 onward `<GeoLocationConfiguration>` configuration has been changed as `<OperationAnalyticsConfiguration>`. Please refer [IoTS 3.2.0 Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS320/Monitoring+Devices+Using+Location+Based+Services#MonitoringDevicesUsingLocationBasedServices-Settingupgeofencing) for more details.

**2. New remote feature in devicemgt.**
This feature is only work with COPE type enrollments. You might need to enroll your device as COPE device, by installing vendor signed system service. Please refer [Integrating the Android System Service Application documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IOTS320/Integrating+the+Android+System+Service+Application) for more details about integrating the system service.